# Running an Oracle query from the command line

Tags: oracle

I have written a simple script and saved it on my machine's C drive (root)  I log into sqlplus via the command line.  Once connected, I enter @C:\myscript.sql and hit enter.  I get a new line with a number and there is no way to get out of it but Ctrl+C.   I haven't done command line or scripts in 15 years or more and I know I'm doing something stupid.  Has anyone else had this issue?  The server is Windows Server 2003 and running Oracle 10.02.  Thanx.

Comment: First of all I'd copy the contents of your script into an SQL editor or IDE of your choice (TOAD, SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer, SQLplus) and try to run it. May be there are some variables (like `&1`) in the script or some statements just need quite some time.

Comment: My guess is that you want a `/` on a separate line as the last line of your .sql file.  Without seeing what you're doing, however, that's just a guess.

Comment: `DECLARE
  l_exists INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_exists
    FROM "MyDB"."BPLAN_III_MAIN"
   WHERE "BUDGETFY"= 2015 AND "BUDGETTYPE" = 'PB'
     AND ROWNUM = 1;
  IF l_exists = 1 THEN
    DELETE FROM "MyDB"."BPLAN_III_MAIN" WHERE "BUDGETFY"= 2015 AND "BUDGETTYPE" = 'PB';
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not Found');
  END IF;
END;`      I can never get the formatting working correctly on here.  Hopefully this is readable.

Comment: Putting the / at the end did the trick!   It has been so long since I've done command line.  Enterprise Manager spoiled me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the / at the end did the trick!   It has been so long since I've done command line.  Enterprise Manager spoiled me.  Thank you!